# Trouble Converting Numeric Date to YMD in Shiny After read_csv

Tags: r, shiny

Hello I have a shiny application where I upload a file from my local machine. A problem I am having is the date in my csv converts to numeric in Shiny. I tried to covert back to date but I can not get it to go back to YMD format.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
           fileInput("test", "test")
        ),
        mainPanel(
         tableOutput("testtab")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    data = reactive({
        req(input$test)
        dat = as.data.frame(read_csv(input$test$datapath))
        dat$Date = round(as.numeric(dat$Date),2)
        dat$Date = as.Date(dat$Date)
        return(dat)
    })

    output$testtab <- renderTable({
      data() 
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I would like the "Date" column to be an actual Date in YMD format. As you can see, I have tried a few things but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: what is the format of date in your csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.character`. This seems to work

```
 data = reactive({
    req(input$test)
    dat = as.data.frame(read_csv(input$test$datapath))
    dat = dat %>% mutate_at(vars(Date), list(~as.character(.)))
    return(dat)
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Kay. This worked great. Would you mind quickly explaining why your are turning Date to a list and using the ~ ? thank you

Comment: Hi Adam, good to know this worked for you. I am not turning Date into a list. The `list(~ ...)` makes `as.character` an anonymous function within the call to `mutate_at()`. In other words, I don't have to define a function that takes a numeric vector and returns a character vector before passing it onto the `mutate_at()` call.